# Can Xcode 12 coexist with Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to install Xcode 12, but I would also like to keep Xcode 11 installed on my machine.  Last time I simply moved Xcode 10 to /Application/Xcode_10 and then installed Xcode 11, with no problems.  Can I do the same with Xcode 12 and 11 without problems?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Long Answer: You can find older versions of xcode at https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/ by looking for "Command Line Tools and Older Versions of XCode"

If you are compiling from the command line, you may need to use the "xcode-select" command to specify which version of XCode you want to use.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, previously I did the same thing between major versions of Xcode (e.g., 10 and 11).  Just thought I'd confirm.